# Is this formal proof of the "Proof by Contradiction" derivation rule correct?

Tags: logic, formal-proofs

I started out with Shawn Hedman's "*A First Course in Logic: An Introduction to Model Theory, Proof Theory, Computatibility, and Complexity*" to learn the very basics. When I got to "Proof by Contradiction" derivation rule, I tried to derive the conclusion from the premises as an exercise, I got there via a different path, but I'm not sure if my solution is sound or wishful thinking.

This is from the book:

> Premises:  ∪ {F } ⊢ G
>                    ∪ {F } ⊢ ¬G
> Conclusion:  ⊢ ¬F
>
> | Line | Statement | Justification |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | ∪ {F} ⊢ G | Premise |
> | 2 | ∪ {¬G} ⊢ ¬F | Contrapositive applied to 1 |
> | 3 | ∪ {F} ⊢ ¬G | Premise |
> | 4 | ∪ {¬¬G} ⊢ ¬F | Contrapositive applied to 3 |
> | 5 | ⊢ ¬F | Proof by cases applied to 2 and 4 |

and this is the route I took:

| Line | Statement | Justification |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ∪ {F} ⊢ ¬G | Premise |
| 2 | ∪ {F} ⊢ (¬G v ¬F) | V-introduction applied to 1 |
| 3 | ∪ {F} ⊢ (G → ¬F) | →-definition applied to 2 |
| 4 | ∪ {F} ⊢ G | Premise |
| 5 | ∪ {F} ⊢ ¬F | →-elimination applied to 3 and 4 |
| 6 | ∪ {¬F} ⊢ ¬F | assumption |
| 7 | ⊢ ¬F | Proof by cases applied to 5 and 6 |

Comment: I also asked a similar question on Computer Science stack exchange on [How to start with verifying a formal proof programmatically?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/161184/how-to-start-with-verifying-a-formal-proof-programmatically), as I would love to learn to verify my own solutions, so if you have any suggestion, please consider dropping an answer or comment there as well. Thanks!